# GridView not fitting to the screen

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, picasso

I am trying to learn android development from Udacity.

I am trying to use picaso to populate a grid view and try to find the images fit the screen.

Desired output should be some thing like this.

[output required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MFuL.jpg)

The output which I am getting.

[output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK8MG.jpg)

My xml file

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="2"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
/>
```

My getView method from adapter class which extends BaseAdapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView iImageView;

    if(convertView == null){
        iImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    }else {
        iImageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(imageResource[0])
            .into(iImageView);

    iImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView
            .LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            , GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    Log.v("data", "Height:" + Integer.toString(iImageView.getHeight()));
    Log.v("data", "Width:" + Integer.toString(iImageView.getWidth()));

    return iImageView;
}
```

Issue that I am facing is that there is a white space between each column and between the borders of the screen. I don't want that. I want it to be like me desired output.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I tried running this code on a nexus 4 emulator with api 22. And the size of the image is 185 x 277 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using new ImageView to create an ImageView with no properties set, try inflating a layout that contains the ImageView along with the properties for that ImageView that makes sense.  For example, you'll probably want to set [android:scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType) to "centerCrop". Currently it looks like the images are being scaled down to fit the space given by GridView, because it's not a perfect fit.

You could also call methods on your ImageView to set various properties, but I think for you it might be better to express it in an XML layout.

Comment: I didn't create a xml file for the `ImageView` . But I set the scale type to `centerCrop` through a method & it worked for me. And I also changed the width and height of the `ImageView` to `MATCH_PARENT` from `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944627/gridview-and-its-images-is-not-fit-for-all-screensize

Answer (score 0):

Try use custom layout with simple Linear or Relative. Set background color for this layout end set math parent for width. Somethime color for background help so much